# auth_mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, apache2

I have a directory with `auth_mysql` in a `virtualhost` file -- password protected using a mysql user/pass combo.

The problem I have is one file inside that directory needs to be accessed without a user/pass. Is there a way I can pass the user/pass within the php file? Or exclude the one file?

What would I put between the code below?

```
<Location /password-protected>
   ...mysql password protection
   require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: This question is too vague. Where did that XML come from?

Comment: It looks like it's from httpd.conf, so it doesn't belong here either... but I can't seem to propose a move, probably since it's been moved already.

Comment: The webmasters guys punted an Apache configuration question? Funny.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<Files>` directive inside of `<Location>` for the file you want to exclude:

```
<Location /password-protected>
    ...mysql password protection...
    require valid-user
    <Files "this-file-is-not-protected.html">
        Satisfy Any
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</Location>
```